# How can I construct a json with arrays and objects in java

Tags: java, json, gson

I need a json in the following structure to pass as request body to my service.

```js
{
  "i":[
    {
      "a":{
        "o1":"str1";
        "o2":234;
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I can either pass a map like 
<"i[0].a.o1", "str1">
<"i[0].a.02", 345>
 or pass them as string like
"i[0].a.o1"="str1"&"i[0].a.02"=345

to construct the Json.

How can I convert the map or string input to the json structure above?
Should I use inner classes for 'I' and 'A' and just use GsonUtils.getString(I)?

Comment: Make sure that your Json is actually valid. Have you tried it on https://jsonlint.com for example?

Comment: Indeed, more specific, an object key must be a string, and a string must be enclosed with double quotes. So `i:[` must be `"i":[`. That also goes for `a`, `o1` and `o2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45367328/2735286: the Jackson library provides very nice features for serializing, deserializing objects to and from JSON.

Here is some sample code which creates the map structure you proposed, serializes it and then deserializes and checks, if the deserialized structure is the same as the original one.

```
public class JacksonMapperTest {

    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Object> root = provideMap(); // Create map
        String json = convertToJson(root); // Convert to string
        System.out.println(json); // Print json
        Map<String, Object> rootClone = convertToMap(json); // Convert string to map
        System.out.println(root.equals(rootClone)); // Check, if the original and deserialized objects are the same.
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> convertToMap(String json) throws IOException {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>> typeRef
                = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Object>>() {};
        return mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
    }

    private static String convertToJson(Map<String, Object> root) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(root);
    }

    private static Map<String, Object> provideMap() {
        Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<>();
        List<Map<String, Object>> i = new ArrayList<>();
        root.put("i", i);
        Map<String, Object> element = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> a = new HashMap<String, Object>() {
            {
                put("o1", "str1");
                put("o2", 234);
            }
        };
        i.add(element);
        element.put("a", a);
        return root;
    }
}
```

If you run this code this is what you will see in the console:

```
{
  "i" : [ {
    "a" : {
      "o1" : "str1",
      "o2" : 234
    }
  } ]
}
true
```

If you want to used Jackson in your project, you can create a Maven project with these dependencies in the pom.xml file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>
```

For more infos on Jackson, check: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should try [jackson api](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/). believe me, it will make your life way easier.

using this api, you can guarantee that you have a valid json object. also, you can easily build your json nodes.